# Add audio file to post using custom term meta field as link

Tags: shortcode, variables, audio

I am trying to add an audio file to my custom post type using a custom term meta field as a link, but I can't get it right.

Here is how I would normally display a custom term meta field:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy-name');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
$term_id = $term->term_id;
echo get_term_meta( $term_id, 'term-meta-field-name', true );
}?>
```

I'm assuming I have to turn it into a variable, but I'm not sure how. Any ideas?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode([audio src="link"]); ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Using this code I was able to use my custom meta field as the link in the audio shortcode.

First I created a function in functions.php:

```
function audio_link() {
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy-name');
    $result = "";
    if (is_array($terms) || is_object($terms)){
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    $result .= get_term_meta( $term_id, 
    'term-meta-field-name', true );
        }
    }
        return $result;
    }
```

Then I inserted the function into the shortcode like this:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[audio src="'. audio_link()  .'"]');?>`

Hope this helps anyone else with this problem!